# Is there a way to develop OSGi bundles without opening or importing the dependent bundles in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, m2eclipse, tycho

When you develop OSGi bundles using eclipse, there are many denpendent bundles to be imported and opened. When there're many bundles, setting up projects is time-comsuming and difficult, especially to newbies .

I've tried the Tycho plugin and m2e; it seems that they are not for this goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse [Target Platform](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/preference_pages/target_platform.htm) concept.

Moreover, with some luck and persistence, you can use remote P2 site as a Target Platform definition in Eclipse. Since you can export Target Platform definition as a file, that means the whole setup for developers will be importing project with that file and selecting this target platform in Eclipse preferences. The Eclipse will download the whole bunch of dependencies itself. For more details see the blog post [here](http://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/provisioning-your-target-platform-as-local-p2-site/).

Also, since you can use that P2 site as a repository for Tycho builds, that allows you to make Tycho use the same set of dependencies as you use in Eclipse making the build more stable. You can host P2 site as a static web content or use repository, like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) (however, only commercial version supports P2 repositories, so I have not tried that myself).